# Common app.json file for VS2017 solution with many projects. How to reference and locate a common config file

Tags: c#

I have a VS2017 solution made up of many projects. Most of these projects are individual executables that will be scheduled single job executables.  1 project is  a web application and 1 project is a Library that stores configuration information.  I want all the projects to share the same config file that maps to the library just mentioned. Where should I put my app.json file that populates the library in the configuration class? And how do I reference the file?  Currently it uses current directory but each executable has a different directory in the build structure.  The library is defined as below.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace GeoAppConfiguration
{
    public class NT
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class CPCreds
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public class Ubi
    {
        public string URL { get; set; }
    }
    public class GeoAppConfiguration
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public CPCreds CPcreds { get; set; }
        public NT NT { get; set; }
        public Ubi Ubi { get; set; }
        public GeoAppConfiguration()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("app.json");
            var config = builder.Build();
            ConfigurationBinder.Bind(config, this);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1-
I have the app.json file linked to all the projects but am still getting an error about file not found when running the individual projects.  If I copy the file it works fine.

Comment: app.json is just name/value pair. you can create name which has value pointing to a common config file

Comment: Right but my question is how do I make a config file common across the whole solution.

Comment: Add solution item/folder. Then add file "AS Link". Then you can share this file among many projects. Edited in one it will be reflected in all

Comment: So I did the As Link method now.  But when I try to open the IO file not found error.
Here is my code            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("app.json");

Comment: There should be a property setting on that file link that allows you to set it as "content" and "copy always". If you set these, when you build, the file should be in the published set